# Kafka to redis syscronis

Tags: apache-kafka, redis, apache-kafka-connect

After moving the data Kafka to redis i am getting below values

how to view the data

KEYS *

1. "__kafka.offset.redisdatamove.0"

Comment: Are you asking how to run a `SCAN` query in Redis? If you don't know how to use Redis, then why write Kafka data to it?

Comment: No , I am getting the results like

Comment: root@90c79aa80289:/data# redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> select 1
OK
127.0.0.1:6379[1]> keys *
1) "__kafka.offset.redisdatamove1.0"
127.0.0.1:6379[1]>

i am getting  the below results in redis  how to resolve the redis data CDC

1) "__kafka.offset.redisdatamove1.0"


127.0.0.1:6379[1]> get "__kafka.offset.redisdatamove1.0"
"{\"topic\":\"redisdatamove1\",\"partition\":0,\"offset\":0}"
127.0.0.1:6379[1]>

Comment: CDC Postgres to redis

Comment: '{ "name": "sc-n", "config": { "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector", "tasks.max": "1", "database.hostname": "172.18.1.221", "database.port": "1236", "database.user": "postgres", "database.password": "postgres_nave1085", "database.dbname": "postgres",   "database.server.name": "d",  "schema.whitelist": "public", "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": kafka:9092", "database.history.kafka.topic": "s", "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter",    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter" } }'

Comment: My soure connector

Comment: 1) The offsets data isn't the real data from Postgres 2) Please [edit] the question rather than use comments